# How to set English as default language instead of Tamil?

Tags: language-support

The default language used in our laptop is Tamil. We don't know how to switch back to English. If we type something we are getting something.

We don't know the font name or version. Even the Menu bar and task bar contents are in Tamil.

Comment: "If we type something we are getting something. " doesn't make sense. Please provide proper information.

Answer (score 2):

Open a terminal and type the command:

```
LANG=C gnome-control-center
```

This will open the system preferences application in English, and under "Language Support" you can change the language to what you want.

Comment: Good advice! However, if the LANGUAGE env. variable is set (which is often the case in Ubuntu), changing LANG isn't sufficient, but you need to do `LANGUAGE=en gnome-control-center`

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson, I had tested it and it worked so I had to look up the precedence for the different env variables :) While normally `LANGUAGE` overrides all else, [it doesn't apply when the locale is set to `C`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/The-LANGUAGE-variable.html) so `LC_ALL=C` or `LANG=C` will be enough even when `LANGUAGE` is set.

Comment: Aha, I tested the other way around, i.e. from English to some other language... Thanks for letting us know - I stand corrected. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

- Open *System Settings >> Language Support*.
- In the *Language Support* window that appears, you will see a list of languages that your computer can use.
- I suppose in your current settings **Tamil** will be on the top. Just drag **English** to the top. After changing make sure that the list looks somewhat like this:

[image]